# Magento 1 Order Grid Filter by Website instead Store

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento, and need to add filter by website to Sales > Orders page.
I try to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid and add following code:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
   $this->addColumn('website', array(
          'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Website'),
          'index' => 'store_id',
          'type'  => 'options',
          'width' => '70px',
          'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
    ));
}
```

[image]

This is the result, only the English store have website associated.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
protected function _filterWebsiteConditionCallback($collection, $column)
{
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($value);

        foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
            $stores = $group->getStores();
            foreach ($stores as $store) {
                $ids[] = $store->getId();
            }
        }

        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', $ids);

        return $this;
}


protected function _prepareColumns()
{
   $this->addColumn('website', array(
          'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Website'),
          'index' => 'store_id',
          'type'  => 'options',
          'width' => '70px',
          'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
          'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterWebsiteConditionCallback'),
    ));
}
```